# Headers in API Gateway Authorization are not been read

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've implemented a Lambda Function to the authorization and i'm getting errors in my test: the headers are empty. I could check that printing the headers in the console (Cloudwatch).

This is the beginning of my handler:

```
public class Authorizer implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, AuthorizerResponse> {

    public AuthorizerResponse handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent request, Context context) {
        Map<String, String> headers = request.getHeaders();
        System.out.println("headers: " + headers);
        String authorization = headers.get("Authorization");
...
```

And this is the result:
[image]

Talking about the Authorizer, I set up this way:
[image]

And finally, I have my Api Gateway set up this way:

**Method Request**
[image]

**Integration Request**
[image]

What do I have wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to access the headers in your Lambda authorizer function or the integration Lambda function?

Also, in Integration Request, the value should be '  method.request.headers.Authorization'. You don't need 'body' here.

Comment: In the authorizer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your question here.

You are using a TOKEN type Lambda authorizer. This will pass the "Authorization" header value as a token. You can see the below sample Lambda event data -

```
{ 
  type: 'TOKEN',
  methodArn:'arn:aws:execute-api:$AWS_REGION:$ACCOUNT_ID:$API_ID/$STAGE/$RESOURCE/',
  authorizationToken: 'allow' 
}
```

You might have to modify your code accordingly to retrieve this token.

Alternatively, you can use a REQUEST-based Lambda authorizer function. This will send input to Lambda authorizer as a combination of headers, query string parameters, stageVariables, and $context variables. You can then use your existing code to retrieve the headers from the request.

As for setting a mapping template and "Authorization" header in Method Request and Integration Request, you don't need that unless you are planning to pass it to the integration Lambda function as well.